# Any possibility of adding new UI components within the Kibana Dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

Let's say I'm having few `Kibana` dashboards created upfront, and what I need to know is that will it be possible for me to add a UI component, for example a print `button`  within the dashboard itself, in order for the user to print the dashboard externally?  Apart from the feature to export it as a `PDF`, which is given by `Kibana` implicitly.

Any help could be appreciated. :)

Comment: Yes you can check this article on how to achieve this: http://logz.io/blog/kibana-visualizations/

Comment: Thanks @Val, I'll have a look and get back. :)